# Laravel how to update multiple id values

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel how to update multiple id valus in table

```
print_r($test); exit();
Array ( [0] => 185 [1] => 216 )
$report = Test::find($test);
$report->status = "A";
$report->save();
```

Comment: It depends on ids you want to save into table. There are 2 approach save with comma separated or save as ref in another table.

Comment: Do you want to update just status column for multi ids?

Comment: yES .............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Test::whereIn('id', $test)->update(['status' => "A"]);
```

Good luck